# If a function has a removable discontinuity, is it continuous at that point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, continuity

Say I have a function of the form
$$\frac{x+3}{x^2 - 9 }$$
this can be factorized, and reduced to:
$$\frac{1}{x-3}$$
In the first form, the function is discontinuous at $x = \pm 3 $. However the second form, is only discontinuous at $x = 3$. Does that mean that, the function is discontinuous only at x = 3 ? I have read other posts here that said evaluating functions at undefined points does not make sense, but then how does one test for continuity?

Comment: so, the function is discontinuous at x = 3 ?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872247/function-with-a-removable-discontinuity)

Comment: Sorry, got it backwards. The first function is undefined at $x=-3.$ It is not discontinuous at $-3,$ nor is it continuous at $x=-3.$ It is undefined there. Both continuity and discontinuity at $x=-3$ require $f(-3)$ is defined.

Comment: Many books denote discontinuities at undefined points! I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answers your confusion.

Discontinuities are points where the function is not continuous. Given a function $f(x)$, it is continuous at point $a$ if
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$$

So a discontinuity is a point simply *not* satisfying this. If a function is undefined, it in particular does not satisfiy the condition, since the right hand side is undefined and therefore can't be equal to anything. The function in question is undefined for $x=\pm 3$, causing $x=\pm 3$ to be discontinuities.

Answer (score 5):

In the first form the function is *not defined* at $x = \pm 3$. Those points are not in the domain. The function is continuous on its domain. The second form is the same function as the first where both are defined, and adds the point $x=-3$ to the domain in such a way as to make the new function continuous on its (larger) domain. That's what it means to "remove the singularity" at $x=-3$. There is no way to remove the singularity at $x=3$ that will create a function continuous there.

Comment: In many math books and online examples, whenever I am asked to find the "discontinuities" of a function, they always end up being the undefined points? Why is that? Is it an oversimplification? I am getting really confused.

Comment: The discussions in those "many math books"  are a little sloppy/oversimplified to make the authors' points in shorter sentences than would be required to get the words exactly right. I think that's usually OK. Now that you know the full story you can fill in the right words when you see these discussions.

Comment: But it is a fair statement to say the function is not continuous at a point P, that lies out of its domain, right?

Comment: @RSM It's literally not correct. To state the definition of continuity you need the value of the function at the point. Whether or not it's "fair" to elide that is a matter of opinion. The subtlety is what led to your good question in the first place.

Comment: at that point the condition for continuity is not satisfied since the function is undefined, so the function is discontinuous at that point. By fair, I meat “valid”, my bad !